# perl- extract duplicate sequences from a multi-fasta file

Tags: perl

I have a big fasta file **input.fasta** which consists many duplicate sequences. I want to enter a header name and extract out all the sequences with the matching header. I know this could be done easily done with awk/sed/grep but I need a Perl code.

**input.fasta**

```
>OGH38127_some_organism
PAAALGFSHLARQEDSALTPKHYTWTAPGEGDVRAPCPVLNTLANHEFLPHNGKNITVDK
AITALGDAMNISPALATTFFTGGLKTNPTPNATWFDLDMLHKHNVLEHDGSLSRRDMHFD
TSNKFDAATFANFLSYFDANATVLGVNETADARARHAYDMSKMNPEFTITSSMLPIMVGE
SVMMMLVWGSVEEPGAQRDYFEYFFRNERLPVELGWTPGETEIGVPVVTAMITAMVAASP
TDVP
>ABC14110_some_different_org_name
WWVAPGPGDSRGPCPGLNTLANHGYLPHDGKGITLSILADAMLDGFNIARSDALLLFTQ
AIRTSPQYPATNSFNLHDLGRDQLNRHNVLEHDASLSRADDFFGSNHIFNETVFDESRAY
AMLANSKIARQINSKAFNPQYKFTSKTEQFSLGEIAAPIIAFGNSTSGEVNRTLVEYFFM
NERLPIELGWKKSEDGIALDDILRVTQMISKAASLITPSALSWTAETLTP
>OGH38127_some_organism
LPWSRPGPGAVRAPCPMLNTLANHGFLPHDGKNISEARTVQALGRALNIEKELSQFLFEK
ALTTNPHTNATTFSLNDLSRHNLLEHDASLSRQDAYFGDNHDFNQTIFDETRSYWPHPVI
DIQAAALSRQARVNTSIAKNPTYNMSELGLDFSYGETAAYILILGDKDFGKVNRSWVEYL
FENERLPVELGWTRHNETITSDDLNTMLEKVVN
.
.
.
```

I have tried with the following script but it is not giving any output.

**script.pl**

```
#!/perl/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter a fasta header to search for:\n";
my $head = <>;

my $file = "input.fasta";
open (READ, "$file") || die "Cannot open $file: $!.\n";
my %seqs;
my $header;

while (my $line = <READ>){
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/^>(.*)\n//;
    if ($line =~ m/$head/){
        $header = $1;
    }
}
close (READ);

open( my $out , ">", "out.fasta" ) or die $!;

my @count_seq = keys %seqs;
foreach (@count_seq){
    print $out $header, "\n";
    print $out $seqs{$header}, "\n";
}

exit;
```

Please help me correct this script.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the [Bioperl](https://bioperl.org/) module [Bio::SeqIO](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::SeqIO) to handle the parsing of the fasta files, it becomes really simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my ($file, $name) = @ARGV;
my $in = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => $file, -format => "fasta");
my $out = Bio::SeqIO->new(-fh => \*STDOUT, -format => "fasta");

while (my $s = $in->next_seq) {
  $out->write_seq($s) if $s->display_id eq $name;
}
```

run with `perl grep_fasta.pl input.fasta OGH38127_some_organism`

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to store the sequences in memory, you can print them directly when reading the file. Use a flag variable (`$inside` in the example) that tells you whether you're reading the desired sequence or not.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($file, $header) = @ARGV;

my $inside;
open my $in, '<', $file or die $!;
while (<$in>) {
    $inside = $1 eq $header if /^>(.*)/;
    print if $inside;
}
```

Run as

```
perl script.pl file.fasta OGH38127_some_organism > output.fasta
```